# Next.js global.css only works when i paste the code in page.tsx file and doesn't when i paste in any of the components

Tags: css, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am new to nextjs and i was following the following vedio 
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzqNLDMSdMc&ab_channel=TheBraveCoders"
Thats when i Noticed CSS was not being Applied to HeaderTop (The very first component he made)

> HeaderTop

```
import React from "react";

import { BsFacebook, BsTwitter, BsInstagram, BsLinkedin } from "react-icons/bs";

const HeaderTop = () => {
  return (
    <div className="border-b border-gray-200 hidden sm:block">
      <div className="container py-4">
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
          <div className="hidden lg:flex gap-1">
            <div className="header_top__icon_wrapper">
              <BsFacebook />
            </div>
            <div className="header_top__icon_wrapper">
              <BsTwitter />
            </div>
            <div className="header_top__icon_wrapper">
              <BsInstagram />
            </div>
            <div className="header_top__icon_wrapper">
              <BsLinkedin />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="text-gray-500 text-[12px]">
            <b>FREE SHIPPING</b> THIS WEEK ORDER OVER - $55
          </div>

          <div className="flex gap-4">
            <select
              className="text-gray-500 text-[12px] w-[70px]"
              name="currency"
              id="currency"
            >
              <option value="USD $">USD $</option>
              <option value="EUR €">EUR €</option>
              <option value="INR">INR</option>
            </select>

            <select
              className="text-gray-500 text-[12px] w-[80px]"
              name="language"
              id="language"
            >
              <option value="English">English</option>
              <option value="French">French</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeaderTop;
```

> localhost:3000/
> [image]]
> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8uQ9.png)

## These are the other files:

> layout.tsx

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import HeaderTop from '@/componenets/HeaderTop'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <HeaderTop />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

> page.tsx

```
import Image from 'next/image'

import HeaderTop from '@/componenets/HeaderTop'
import HeaderMain from '@/componenets/HeaderMain'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    
    <main>
    </main>
  )
}
```

It works in the vedio and it starts working when i paste the code from HeaderTop.tsx to page.tsx

> page.tsx (After Edit)

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import { BsFacebook, BsTwitter, BsInstagram, BsLinkedin } from "react-icons/bs";
import HeaderTop from '@/componenets/HeaderTop'
import HeaderMain from '@/componenets/HeaderMain'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    
    <main>
      <div className="border-b border-gray-200 hidden sm:block">
      <div className="container py-4">
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
          <div className="hidden lg:flex gap-1">
            <div className="header_top__icon_wrapper">
              <BsFacebook />
            </div>
            <div className="header_top__icon_wrapper">
              <BsTwitter />
            </div>
            <div className="header_top__icon_wrapper">
              <BsInstagram />
            </div>
            <div className="header_top__icon_wrapper">
              <BsLinkedin />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="text-gray-500 text-[12px]">
            <b>FREE SHIPPING</b> THIS WEEK ORDER OVER - $55
          </div>

          <div className="flex gap-4">
            <select
              className="text-gray-500 text-[12px] w-[70px]"
              name="currency"
              id="currency"
            >
              <option value="USD $">USD $</option>
              <option value="EUR €">EUR €</option>
              <option value="INR">INR</option>
            </select>

            <select
              className="text-gray-500 text-[12px] w-[80px]"
              name="language"
              id="language"
            >
              <option value="English">English</option>
              <option value="French">French</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

After that it continues to work i have tried it in 2 diffrent browsers and it keeps on working as long as i dont change anything but as soon as i restart and the page.tsx does not containt the code it fails

> localhost:3000/
> [image]

## Does Anyone have Any Clue Why it is Happening And How to Fix it, Here is the entire complete project

https://github.com/AbdulMoqueet/shopping-web-app

I tried Changing browsers just in case the issue was with the cache but no luck same result, i ended up pasting it in page.tsx file which worked temporarily as long as i didnt add any classes

Comment: You need to add import of global.css in your _App.js (ts) file to make it work globally

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's due to your `tailwind.config.ts` did not set correctly, you should update the paths in `content` where you want tailwindcss to work.

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/modules/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
}
```

Comment: Does this method fix your issue?